# How to calculate this complicated integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried solving this integral by starting with setting $1+x^2$ to be new unknown $u$. What should I do next ?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1+2x}(1+x^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}+e^{x^2}x^4}{e^{x^2}(1+x^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

Comment: It simplifies dramatically if you break the fraction up into two pieces (you know $\frac{a+b}c=\frac ac+\frac bc$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-1)^2}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi} $$
and:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^{7/2}}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin^4(\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{2}{5}.$$

Comment: So, the solution is "A"+"B" ? Why is the second integral transformed into "cos & sin" variant ?